# Use a Action Function from controller in umbraco8

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, umbraco

i'm creating a new website with umbraco8 i have a problem how to load an Action in Controller from a view of Homepage

**Homepage view**

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.HomePage>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels;
@{
    Layout = "webBase.cshtml";
}

@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderHomeSlider", "HomePage"); }
```

**Homepage Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using HAWELE.Models;
using Archetype.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;
using System.Threading;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController;
 public class HomePageController :  Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{   

    public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }
    private const string PARTIAL_VIEW_HOME_FOLDER = "~/Views/Partials/HomePage/";

    public ActionResult RenderHomeSlider(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return PartialView(PARTIAL_VIEW_HOME_FOLDER + "_HomeSlider.cshtml");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not look like umbraco 8 code. Are you trying to convert an old website?

Comment: yes, how i can call the same functionality in umbraco 8

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't related to Umbraco. `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute is missing on the calling method:

```
RenderAction(HtmlHelper, String, String)
```

Invokes the specified **child action method** using the specified controller name and renders the result inline in the parent view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Remove the index method from your controller.  It is not relevant in a surfacecontroller.

Modify the RenderHomeSlider Action to:

```
public ActionResult RenderHomeSlider()
{
    return PartialView(PARTIAL_VIEW_HOME_FOLDER + "_HomeSlider.cshtml");
}
```

This line in your view

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("RenderHomeSlider", "HomePage"); }
```

should change to

```
@Html.Action("RenderHomeSlider", "HomePage")
```

This should render whatever html is in `_HomeSlider.cshtml`

It's not clear whether your `_HomeSlider.cshtml` partial requires any model to be passed into so I am assuming it doesn't.

To test that the above works, you can just put some simple text in your partial and see if it rendered on the page.

I don't know what the rest of your code looks like so can't say exactly whether what you are trying to achieve here is the most expedient way to do it.

Good luck